# How I can get table data , search by firstName and lastName , using remoteFunction

Tags: search, grails, html-table

User.groovy

```
class User {

String firstName
String lastName
String email
Integer age

static constraints = {
    firstName blank:false, nullable:false, maxSize:50
    lastName  blank:false, nullable:false, maxSize:50
    email     email:true, blank:false, nullable:false
    age       min:18, blank:false, nullable:false
}
}
```

UserController.groovy

```
class UserController {

static scaffold = true

def index() {
    redirect(action: 'search')

}

def search() {


    }

def searchTable(){
    def list = User.list()
    [ list:list ]


    render(template: 'searchTable', model:[ list : list ])
}

}
```

search.gsp

```
<h1>Please enter First Name or Last Name for search</h1>
<div id="lb">

    <label for="first_name">First Name Search:</label>
    <g:textField name="first_name"/><br/>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name Search:</label>
    <g:textField name="last_name"/><br/>


</div>

<div id="insertSearchResultsHere">

</div>
```

_searchTable.gsp

```
<%@ page import="com.myapp.User" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<title>Users</title>
<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>

 <div id="list-menu" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
 <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>First Name</th>

        <th>Last Name</th>

        <th>Email</th>

        <th>Age</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${list}" var="user" status="i">
        <tr>

            <td>${user.firstName}</td>

            <td>${user.lastName}</td>

            <td>${user.email}</td>

            <td>${user.age}</td>

        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

How I can search in search.gsp by firstName or lastName  and return data form serachTable tamplate (show in section `id="insertSearchResultsHere"`), using remoteFunction in grails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that remoteFunction won't work for you in this case - at least not easily, because you need to gather the information provided by the user in the input fields.

What you need in my opinion is a `formRemote` - after all, you are rendering a search form - you just didn't add the form tag yet :) . So:

1. surround your input fields by a g:formRemote tag.
2. add an input submit before the end of the form. It will be used to trigger the form submit (and thus the search as well).

For this, you only have to change `search.gsp`:

```
<h1>Please enter First Name or Last Name for search</h1>
<div id="lb">
    <g:formRemote name="userSearch" url="${[controller: 'user', action: 'searchTable']}" method="GET" update="insertSearchResultsHere">
       <label for="firstName">First Name Search:</label>
       <g:textField name="firstName"/><br/>
       <br/><br/>
       <label for="lastName">Last Name Search:</label>
       <g:textField name="lastName"/><br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </g:formRemote>
</div>

<div id="insertSearchResultsHere">

</div>
```

Additionally, you need to actually search by the provided first and last names in the controller:

```
def searchTable(){
    def list = User.withCriteria {
        and {
            if (params.firstName) {
              eq('firstName', params.firstName)
            }
            if (params.lastName) {
              eq('lastName', params.lastName)
            }
        }
    }
    render(template: 'searchTable', model:[ list : list ])
}
```